# Preventing inheritance of scope in nested views?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to prevent $scope to be inherited in nested views in ui-router for AngularJS?

I am working with AngularJS 1.x and ui.router 1.0.0-beta.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ui-view` directive uses inherited scope and it instantiates route controller with this scope. This is default behaviour that isn't supposed to be modified.

If isolated scope is desirable, [route components](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component) should be used instead of route controller/template pairs.

Comment: I see I have to do some restructuring of the code, thanks.